# Error INSERT INTO php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Quisiera hacer una insercion de usuarios en la db. He mirado las preguntas de otros participantes, pero no logro dar con la solucion para insertar el usuario en la tabla.
creé la tabla nuevamnte pero utilizando sql de los recursos, pero sigo teniendo ´problemas con el insert.
Acá hice un var_dump a los `$datos` y a la `$respuesta`, los datos si pasan pero la respuesta me retorna error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi tabla de usuarios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.
Acá tengo el código del controlador usuarios:

```
static public function ctrCrearUsuario()
{
    if (isset($_POST["nuevoUsuario"])){

        if (preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]+$/',$_POST["nuevoNombre"]) &&
            preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoUsuario"]) &&
            preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/', $_POST["nuevoPassword"])){

            $tabla = "usuarios";

            $datos = array(
                "nombre" => $_POST["nuevoNombre"],
                "usuario" => $_POST["nuevoUsuario"],
                "password" => $_POST["nuevoPassword"],
                "perfil" => $_POST["nuevoPerfil"]
            );
            /*var_dump($datos);*/
            $respuesta = ModeloUsuarios::mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos);
            /*var_dump($respuesta);*/


            if ($respuesta == "ok"){
                echo '<script>
                    swal({
                        type: "success",
                        title: "¡El usuario ha sido guardado correctamente",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                        closeOnConfirm: false
                    }).then((result)=>{
                        if(result.value){
                            window.location = "usuarios";
                        }
                    });
                  </script>';
            }

        }else{
            echo '<script>
                    swal({
                        type: "error",
                        title: "¡El usuario no puede ir vacío ni ingresar caracteres especiales.!",
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                        closeOnConfirm: false
                    }).then((result){
                        if(result.value){
                            window.location = "usuarios";
                        }
                    });
                  </script>';
        }
    }
}
```

Modelo usuarios

```
static public function mdlIngresarUsuario($tabla, $datos){
    $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla(nombre, usuario, password, perfil) VALUES (:nombre, :usuario, :password, :perfil)");

    $stmt->bindParam(":nombre", $datos["nombre"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":usuario", $datos["usuario"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":password", $datos["password"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(":perfil", $datos["perfil"], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    if ($stmt->execute()){
        return "ok";
    }else{
        return "error";
    }

    $stmt->close();

    $stmt = null;
}
```

Acá la clase conexion:

```
    <?php
class Conexion{
    public static function conectar(){
        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pos",
        "root",
        "");

        $link->exec("set names utf8");

        return $link;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Verificaste que se esté creando la conexión? haz var_dump($stmt); luego de conectar y muestras el volcado. Si no es el esperado entra a [edit] e incluye el método Conectar() y verifica que PDO esté activo, hay casos en que es necesario incluirlo explícitamente mediante `use PDO;` antes de crear la conexión.

Comment: hola @quevedo, con var_dump($stmt) muestra
object(PDOStatement)#4 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(102) "INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, usuario, password, perfil) VALUES (:nombre, :usuario, :password, :perfil)" }
subi la clase para conexion

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el error que te arroja? para así poder saber exactamente donde empezar a buscar el problema.

Answer (score 0):

cambia en tu consulta en vez de `$tabla` pon usuarios, sino pon así `.$tabla`.

```
$stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, usuario, password, perfil) VALUES (:nombre, :usuario, :password, :perfil)");
```

Revisa que tu base de datos tenga habilitada la opcion de `null` en los campos foto, estado, ultimo login, fecha para que puedas insertar los datos en el registro sin requerir esos campos

Comment: Hola @Tuxor, probé con ambas formas y no funciona.
Gracias

Comment: $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO usuarios (nombre, usuario, password, perfil) VALUES (:nombre, :usuario, :password, :perfil)");

Revisa que tu base de datos tenga habilitada la opcion de null en los campos foto, estado, ultimo login, fecha para que puedas insertar los  datos en el registro sin requerir esos campos.

Comment: funcionó!... lo habia descartado puesto que habia dejado como null la fecha, por probar,, y ahora incluí los demas campos y pasó.
Gracias @Tuxor Max Power

Comment: de nada @FranciscoMorales suerte en tu proyecto!